# change css dynamically on actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

How could I dynamically change the css of a actionLink control on CSHTML page.
Suppose, I am getting a "type" parameter on the CSHTML page and on this "type" parameter basis I want to change the css of "ActionLink" on a CSHTML page.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This :

```
if(type == "somevalue")
{
  @Html.ActionLink("click here","index","Home", null ,new{ @class="myclass" })
}
else
{
  @Html.ActionLink("click here","index","Home", null ,new{ @class="otherclass" })
}
```

OR

```
@Html.ActionLink("click here","index","Home", null ,new{ @class = (type == "somevalue" ? "myclass" : "otherclass") })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Html.ActionLink("Home", "", "", null, (ViewBag.type == "your type") ? new { @class = "typeclass" } : new { @class = "otherclass" })
```